# Adding a new IIS Mime Type without doing an IIS Reset?

Tags: iis, iis-6, reset, mime-type

I have to add a new mime type to an IIS 6.0 web server.

The client would like this done ASAP as it currently isn't serving .flv files.

However, the server is used for other clients and I would like to avoid doing an IIS Reset during working hours.

Does anyone know a way of getting IIS to read the new mime types without a reset?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a temporary solution to this.

You can add the MIME Types to the website only and do not have to do it to the whole server.

This means that a full iisreset is not required and only a kick to the single site in question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but don't know what do you mean by "only a kick to the single site"? Thank you :)